# mdadm RAID5 array recovery stops without SCSI errors

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, lsi

I have an md-based RAID5 array which has been working without issue for about 2 years. Yesterday I've had spontaneous disk and/or PHY resets on one disk (but not actual read errors). md marked the disk as faulty, with the remaining array state being 'clean, degraded', so I tried removing and re-adding it. md started resyncing the array at a good speed (140M/s), but at about 0.6% the resync speed began falling and in about 10 seconds mdadm quit with the message "md: md0: recovery interrupted" without any SCSI or other errors visible in dmesg output (my current SCSI logging level is set to 0x10012DD). This occurred on several attempts. `smartctl -a`, `smartctl -t short` and scanning the first 1% of all disks with `badblocks` didn't turn up any errors. Read-only `xfs_repair -n` on the degraded array showed a bunch of I/O errors and bad checksums, as expected, but after all these exercises resync got past the point where it was quitting earlier. I am now running `badblocks` on the rest of the disks and hoping the array will eventually finish resyncing so I can add fresh disks and finally go up to RAID6, but naturally there is no guarantee this will happen, which leads to the question:

Is it possible to make md resync plow past errors and trash bad blocks? I would very much rather end up with a 0.01% corrupted array than nothing. The data I have in the array is not critical and I can re-check it for errors on higher levels, but recovering it from scratch would take a very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the driver code in raid5.c, it doesn't look to be possible to force md to ignore errors during resync. However, if nothing else helps, as a last resort it is possible to reassemble the array without a mandatory resync by re-creating it with `--assume-clean`, see e.g. [RAID Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_Recovery#Restore_array_by_recreating_.28after_multiple_device_failure.29) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445536).

Answer (score 0):

> Read-only xfs_repair -n on the degraded array showed a bunch of I/O errors and bad checksums, as expected

It is **not** expected: one faulty / missing disk should cause no data corruption in an otherwise good RAID5 array. You probably have multiple unreadable data sector on one or the other disks. While recent `mdadm` versions can be forced to continue recovery, the internal bad blocks list is quite small and reconstruct aborts when it is full.

I suggest you to double-check the health of all your disks.

Comment: That was almost the first thing I did. The disks are all healthy, SMART is clean and extended self-tests passed. The problem seems to have been insufficient power supply, which was causing some disks to reset under load, thus I/O errors.